# Graph Induction: proving a chain of star graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am learning Discrete Math and I came across this problem. I am not sure how I can prove the following problem:

### Prove that a chain of star graphs is 2 colorable?

Comment: For one star color the center with color $1$ and the leaves with color $2$. For a chain of them of size $n$, if the chain has been colored up to the $n-1$ star, then color the center of the $n$-th star with the opposite color as the $(n-1)$-th center and its leaves with the same color as the $(n-1)$-th center.

Comment: All acyclic graphs are 2-colorable.

Comment: To continue on Matthew's comment, just pick a color for a node, color all of its neighbors the opposite color, color all of their neighbors the first color, etc until all of the nodes in the connected component are colored, then move on to the next component. This works since you'll never reach the same node twice.

Comment: sorry, what does chain of graph mean? like each component is a star graph?